# Почему слово "щедрый" нельзя назвать причастием ?

Tags: морфология

Почему слово "щедрый" нельзя назвать причастием,ведь оно тоже произошло от глагола и окончание у него как у прилагательного?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

А от какого глагола? В современном языке связь с глаголом не прослеживается. Но даже происхождение от глагола еще не достаточный признак для причастия. Должны сохраняться глагольные признаки: время, вид. Должен быть суффикс причастия. В слове щедрый суффикса причастия нет. Признака по действию оно тоже не обозначает. Это прилагательное.

Comment: Спасибо ,а где суффикс в слове "идущий",разве это не причастие?

Comment: Идущий по полю - причастие, суфф. -ущ-. Дорогу осилит идущий - переход причастия в существительное.Суфф. остаётся суффиксом, но в словообразовании роли не играет, здесь тоже субстантивация - переход из других частей речи в существительное.

Answer (score 2):

Щедрый - от прилагат. щедръ. Возможно, в праславянском и образовалось от глагола*sked, но в древнерусском было уже прилагательным. Так что не от глагола и не причастие, а прилагательное.А вот от него глагол щедреть и причастие щедреющий.

Answer (score 1):

В словарях старославянской лексики мы находим глаголы щедрити, щедровати, щедрьствовати, однако причастий от них в современном РЯ нет. Можно придумать корявое щедреющий, но где мы возьмем глагольный инфинитив щедреть, вряд ли он наличествует где-нибудь, кроме сетевой разговорной базы. Хотя нет, вру :

"Тороватый в
деле, ловкий, наторелый. Он на все выдумки
тороват. Тороватость ж. свойство, качество по
прилаг. Торово нареч. торовато, щедро, чиво.
Тороватеть, становиться более тороватым,
**щедреть.** Никак он под старость тороватеет!" (В.И.Даль)

Считайте причастие щедреющий моим личным изобретением.

Есть глагол расщедриться, от него образовано действительное причастие прошедшего времени  расщедрившийся. Суффикс -вш.

Щедрый - прилагательное, конечно.

Вопрос интересный, надо бы поощрить, но не могу вроде пока (?)

Comment: Запатентовать не получится, такое причастие(щедреющий)есть, вот в стихотворении, например: http://www.poezia.ru/article.php?sid=69811 
, как и глагол ЩЕДРЕТЬ-становиться щедрым, правда, устаревающий, но он образован от прилагат.ЩЕДРЫЙ, а не наоборот(как синеть от синий).Речь не о слове " щедреющий", а о ЩЕДРЫЙ.

Comment: "Сергей Шелковый 2009-05-12 18:30:52
Рад Вас снова видеть, Генриетта, на фоне всё щедреющей весны. 
 Спасибо за Ваш добрый майский отклик!"
Это - стихи?? Это сетевая лексика, я так и написал в своем ответе! Ну, а щедреть - только у Даля, в побочном упоминании.

Comment: >Вопрос интересный, надо бы поощрить, но не могу вроде пока

Простите, а Вы случайно не @grumant ? Очень у вас стиль ответов похожий. И появились как раз после того как его забанили.

Comment: Надо же, любой участник форума знает стиль груманта и сравнивает его со мной. Спасибо!